# PHP - how to get most recent file from directory AND subdirectories

Tags: php, file, filesystems, subdirectory

I have used the following script to correctly display ALL files from the selected directory and its sub-directories. Does anyone know how to modify this code only echo the most recent file across the directory/subdirectories?

```
function ListFiles($dir) {

    if($dh = opendir($dir)) {

        $files = Array();
        $inner_files = Array();

        while($file = readdir($dh)) {
            if($file != "." && $file != ".." && $file[0] != '.') {
                if(is_dir($dir . "/" . $file)) {
                    $inner_files = ListFiles($dir . "/" . $file);
                    if(is_array($inner_files)) $files = array_merge($files, $inner_files); 
                } else {
                    array_push($files, $dir . "/" . $file);
                }
            }
        }

        closedir($dh);
        return $files;
    }
}


foreach (ListFiles('media/com_form2content/documents/c30') as $key=>$file){
    echo "{aridoc engine=\"google\" width=\"750\" height=\"900\"}" . $file ."{/aridoc}";
}
```

Answer (score 9):

In `PHP5` you can use `RecursiveDirectoryIterator` to recursively scan all files in a directory:

```
$mostRecentFilePath = "";
$mostRecentFileMTime = 0;

$iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator("YOURDIR"), RecursiveIteratorIterator::CHILD_FIRST);
foreach ($iterator as $fileinfo) {
    if ($fileinfo->isFile()) {
        if ($fileinfo->getMTime() > $mostRecentFileMTime) {
            $mostRecentFileMTime = $fileinfo->getMTime();
            $mostRecentFilePath = $fileinfo->getPathname();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for the quick reply, but I need to get the most recent file across directory AND sub-directory. How would I modify the code above?

Comment: @bjornkock so you want to get the file with most recent mtime in a directory and it's sub-dirs?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`filemtime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filemtime.php) to retrieve file's last modified unix timestamp.

Answer (score 1):

you can use this to get last addition file in directory

```
$path = "/path/to/my/dir"; 

$latest_ctime = 0;
$latest_filename = '';    

$d = dir($path);
while (false !== ($entry = $d->read())) {
  $filepath = "{$path}/{$entry}";
  // could do also other checks than just checking whether the entry is a file
  if (is_file($filepath) && filectime($filepath) > $latest_ctime) {
      $latest_ctime = filectime($filepath);
      $latest_filename = $entry;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
$last_mtimes = array(); 
function ListFiles($dir) {

if($dh = opendir($dir)) {

$files = Array();
$inner_files = Array();

while($file = readdir($dh)) {
    if($file != "." && $file != ".." && $file[0] != '.') {
        if(is_dir($dir . "/" . $file)) {
            $inner_files = ListFiles($dir . "/" . $file);
            if(is_array($inner_files)) $files = array_merge($files, $inner_files); 
        } else {
            array_push($files, $dir . "/" . $file);
             $lmtime = filemtime($dir . "/" . $file) ;
             $last_mtimes[$lmtime] = $dir . "/" . $file;
        }
    }
}
 // now ksort your $last_mtimes array
krsort($last_mtimes);
// either return this array or do whatever with the first val
closedir($dh);
return ($last_mtimes);

}
}
// prints in decsending order
foreach (ListFiles('PATH_TO_YOUR_DIRECTORY') as $key=>$file){
echo "{aridoc engine=\"google\" width=\"750\" height=\"900\"}" . $key."=>".$file ."  {/aridoc}";
 }
 // prints last modified files
 echo array_shift(ListFiles('YOUR_DIRECTORY_PATH'));
```

hope this helps

Comment: thank you for the quick reply, but this doesn't seem to work.

Comment: what does  `print_r($last_mtimes);` print. I am curious why wouldn't it work. did a small edit try it out again. mind you that I am not return `$last_mtimes` array

Comment: print_r($last_mtimes) returns: Array ( [1329271076] => logo_lg.jpg ) Array ( [1327908278] => H1B application 2009.pdf ) Array ( [1329271671] => Employee Manual.pdf ) Array ( [1322843201] => Company.docx ) Array ( [1327909484] => prop01-06.JPG )

Comment: but I just need the the most recent file.

Comment: the above code seems to work but it will list all files in descending order of their respective last modified date. You may want to break the for loop after first iteration if you wish. or use `$most_recent_file = array_shift(ListFiles('YOUR_DIRECTORY_PATH'));` to get the most recent modified file

Comment: looks like we are half way there! The code above returns the most recent file, BUT only in the main directory, NOT the sub-directories, meaning that if I place a more recent file in the sub-directory this file will be ignored by the code. I appreciate your help and time as I cannot get this to work across directory and sub-directories. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you use the `filemtime()` function.

This will give you the files last modified date.